how to extend Spine class?
In pixijs project, i want to create class component that extends Spine, but it gives me an error

Uncaught Error: The spineData param is required.

Here is an example:
export class TargetView extends Spine {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.spineData = RESOURCES.getSpineData("shooting");
  }
}

I tried to pass spineData when creating class
target = new TargetView("spinedata);


Welcome to SO! Since Spine is not part of Pixi, it would help tremendously if you could also tell us where we can look up documentation for it. Just from looking at it as it is now without further knowing anything about Spine, I'd suggest that you pass the result of RESOURCES.getSpineData("shooting") right into the super() call like super(RESOURCES.getSpineData("shooting"));, but that's just guessing.

@Davi - That's what I was thinking as well, but shouldn't OP then also add that argument to the constructor's signature?

@DarkBee IMHO that's a question about the architecture, not about the error that the OP faces. The usual answer to your question is - of course - "Yes" :)

    export class TargetView extends Spine {
     constructor(spineData) {
      super(spineData);
      //
     }
   }

you need to pass the spineData that is required to the Spine class you are extending from
